# Reverse method for Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, numbers, reverse, formatter

I need to reverse the amount from formatted number according culture to double value in javascript.

By the use of Intl.NumberFormat method we change number to specific format according to culture. I want reverse method to convert formatted number to actual numeric value.
Example: new Intl.NumberFormat(window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage)

```
var number = 123456.789;

// For German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number));
// → 123.456,789

// For India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(number));
// → 1,23,456.789
```

Anybody having idea please suggest.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: provide the minimum http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, could you please provide a little code example of how you are creating the number, so that we can test it ourselves (an example that works)?

Comment: Generally it's better to store number value as double and format it with Intl function only for display. Isn't that solution suitable for you?

Comment: It having very specific scenario, we can't use the format on display time.